# Proving that $L=\{w\in \Sigma^*: |w|_a= 2^n +273$, $n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ is irregular.

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

I am trying to prove that $L=\{w\in \Sigma^*: |w|_a= 2^n +273$, $n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ is irregular, whereas: $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$.
I tried to use the pumping lemma with no success. I have also tried to prove that there are infinite equivalency classes (thus, $L$ doesn't have a finite automata which accepts it) but I got stuck, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pumping lemma should work.  Let $w = a^m \in L$ with $m$ greater than the pumping constant (this will happen when $m = 2^n+273$ for some $n$, so just choose large enough $n$).  Then if $L$ were regular, there is some $k$ such that for all $c\in \mathbb{N}$, all of $a^{m+ck} \in L$.  Now show that for any $k>0$ and $m$, not all numbers of the form $m+ck$ can be of the form $2^n+273$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did not get the last part.. How can I show that not all numbers of the form $m+ck$ can be of the form $2^n + 273$ ?

Comment: Suppose that they were.  Let $c$ be large enough that $m+ck = 2^n+273$ where $2^n > k$.  Then $2^n + 273 < m+(c+1)k < 2^{n+1} + 273$, a contradiction.